# HTML5 CSS Validation Content-Type Error

Tags: css, html, validation, mime

Hopefully its just a quick one just ran my my first html validation everything worked exception it keeps telling me no content-type found. I've compared it to other html5 sites and I have no idea what's going on. I'm also getting a MIME error when I try to validate my CSS sheet. I'm pretty sure they're related/

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnathansachs.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, your server is failing to include a [Content-Type header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) in the HTTP response. This header is mandatory. It has nothing to do with the HTML document itself.

You need to fix your server or server side program that generates your content.

```
%  curl -I http://nathansachs.com/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 11 Jan 2014 09:24:50 GMT
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
Last-Modified: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 20:32:26 GMT
ETag: "bec00cb-11d5-4ef674648e9f0"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 4565
```

I'd consider upgrading Apache. You are using an older version of a *development branch*. That branch has stabilised and on revision 7 now! (i.e. Apache 2.4.7 is out). Use of experimental code might be the cause of your problem.

Possibly related:

- [Apache2 not sending “Content-Type” in header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633376/apache2-not-sending-content-type-in-header)

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this inside the `<head />` section.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

For HTML5:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8"> <!-- try without quotes as well -->
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this a million times over, im working in html 5 so all i need really is <meta "charset=utf-8">. Anybody else got anything thoughs?